# angular data transfer and usage

Tags: angular, service, components

I have component **A** which has template

```
 <div>component **A**</div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and when I write `site.com/A/B` **A** component loads
makes some operations and sends data to **someService** then loads **B** component
which calls for that **someService** to get data stored by **A** component

here is service

```
  export class someService {
    dataUpdated:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    constructor() { }
    setLatestData(someData) {
      this.dataUpdated.emit(someData);
    }
  }
```

so while **B** component renders it draws that data from someService.

At this point everything looks good.

If I press the link which takes me to `site.com/A/C`

**B** part of html will be changed by Html from **C** component.

But if after that I press the link `site.com/A/B` again

I see **B** component page without data from service. 
How can I modify this project so, that I could generate some data and use it multiple times while switching from one url to another as far as the main **A** component is loaded ?

Comment: https://ngrx.io/

Comment: could you please share your UI screenshot ??